# In Pathfinder, are there any weapon buffs that overcome all forms of Damage Reduction?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage-resistance

Is there a spell in the Pathfinder world that grants a power to melee or ranged weapons similar to the Smite Evil / Smite Good ability to overcome all forms of Damage Reduction?

Answer (score 7):

To clarify, here is the [Smite Evil ability](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/paladin.html#smite-evil) of the Paladin.

> Regardless of the target, smite good attacks automatically bypass any DR the creature might possess

It sounds like you want a spell that effectively mimics this part of the ability.

If you look at the section on [Damage Reduction](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#damage-reduction), you will see there is a segment on "*Overcoming DR*". This states:

> Weapons with an enhancement bonus of +3 or greater can ignore some types of damage reduction, regardless of their actual material or alignment.

Any weapon with an Enhancement bonus of +5 ignores all Damage Reduction except for DR/(-/Slashing/Piercing/Bludgeoning). Note that this only seems to work if the weapon is permanently enchanted, a weapon temporarily enchanted with the [Magic Weapon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/magicWeapon.html#magic-weapon) spell can only bypass DR/magic.

**Aside:** there are two spells to help you bypass specific forms of resistance. But neither of these bypass DR/-

- [Align Weapon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/alignWeapon.html#align-weapon) can get around things like DR/Good
- [Versatile Weapon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/versatileWeapon.html#versatile-weapon) can bypass things like DR/Piercing

**But none of these beat DR/-**. Yep, as far as I can tell, only that Smite ability is capable of completely ignoring DR all together. Worth knowing next time you face [the Tarrasque](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/tarrasque.html#tarrasque) :)

Comment: Extrapolation question: if you wanted to make a weapon with a feature to bypass any form of DR, even if limited in use, could a character with the Smite ability make such a weapon? Even though there is not a spell that emulates that ability?

Comment: That would obviously be a GM call. Frankly, I would rather create a spell that has that ability and then use it appropriately. Both Align Weapon and Versatile Weapon are are 2nd level spells. Not sure how I would price "bypass all DR" though. It's likely at least a 4th level spell. But it seems like it could well be on the same level as like an anti-magic field. http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/magic/designingSpells.html

Answer (score 3):

There is the [Align Weapon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/alignWeapon.html#align-weapon) spell, which will overcome alignment-based DR.
There is also [Versatile Weapon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/versatileWeapon.html#versatile-weapon) which, among other things, will actually allow the use of a Mace of Sharpness ;)

Comment: I thought about both of those spells. They may justify a weapon with "strike anything" feature. I am imagining a +1 Strike Anything (weapon) that allows you to bypass all forms of DR against a single foe once per day. What would the weapon maker need to manufacture such a weapon?